# Save data from Spark to MongoDB and Mysql

Tags: python, mongodb, apache-spark, twitter, pyspark

I am able to save data from spark to Mysql but not to MongoDB and Mysql simultaneously. Can someone tell me how to do this? I have mentioned below my code to flatten JSON, def to save into MongoDB and spark-submit commands.

I am trying to save raw Twitter data to MongoDB.Can someone please guide me?

Code to Flatten JSON for MongoDB:

```
    def convertMongo(rdd):
    try:
        spark = getSparkSessionInstance(rdd.context.getConf())
        df_json =  spark.createDataFrame(rdd.map(lambda x: (_flatten_JSON(json.loads(x[1])))))
        return df_json
    except Exception as e:
        print(str(e))
```

Code to Save to MongoDB:

```
def write_mongo(rdd):
    try:
        mongoDFRDD = convertMongo(rdd)
        if(mongoDFRDD is not None):
            mongoDFRDD.write.format('com.mongodb.spark.sql.DefaultSource').mode('append').option("hos$
    except Exception as e: 
        print(str(e))
```

Spark Submit Command Working:

```
spark-submit --packages org.apache.spark:spark-sql-kafka-0-10_2.11:2.1.1,mysql:mysql-connector-java:5.1.45 --jars spark-streaming-kafka-0-8-assembly_2.11-2.0.0.jar MachineLearningOnStreamDataInSpark2.py
```

Spark Submit Command with MongoDB --conf inclusion not working:

spark-submit --conf spark.logConf=true --conf `"spark.mongodb.input.uri=mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/Twitter.TwitterData?readPreference=primaryPreferred" --conf "spark.mongodb.output.uri=mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/Twitter.TwitterData" --packages org.mongodb.spark:mongo-spark-connector_2.11:2.0.0  --packages org.apache.spark:spark-sql-kafka-0-10_2.11:2.1.1 --jars spark-streaming-kafka-0-8-assembly_2.11-2.0.0.jar MachineLearningOnStreamDataInSpark2.py`

Comment: What do you mean when you say "not working"? Any specific symptoms (exceptions for example)?

Comment: @user6910411 It doesn't throw any errors. But still not saving in MongoDB